# What is your Instagram password when signing in using Facebook?

Tags: facebook, passwords, instagram

Do this:

1. On your phone, create an instagram account using Facebook log in.
2. Now on your desktop web browser, log in using Facebook connect.
3. Now go to delete your account - edit profile -> I'd like to delete my account.

It will ask for your password.

But you never gave it a password in order to create the account.

I tried using my Facebook password, but that didn't work.

Any ideas? The Instagram account management seems quite broken.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it right. When you login account using Facebook it synchronize your account with Facebook by using details from Facebook and didn't ask for password. But when you are deleting account they want you to login it separately and then delete.

From the [Instagram Help Center](https://help.instagram.com/448136995230186/) page, To delete your account:

- Leave the Instagram app and log into `instagram.com` from a computer. You cannot delete it from your mobile application.
- Click your username in the top right and then select Edit Profile.
- Click I'd like to delete my account in the bottom right.

> For security reasons, we can't delete an account for you. You’ll need to be able to log into your account to delete it. If you can't remember your password or username, see some [tips for logging in](https://help.instagram.com/409847499070242).